# Pause flash video (HTML5 fallback) with external link?

Tags: jquery, flash, html5-video, video.js

I am using video.js to display html5 video. I also have a jquery function to pause all videos on the page with a link click. This works fine.

Except... If the browser doesn't support html5 video, it falls back to flash (video is displayed as a .swf). My pause function has no effect on flash. So I need a way to pause the .swf with an external link. I've only found solutions that work if you know the names of labels and components in the flash movie. But I don't know that. Here is how the .swf is output:

```
<object id="tkavideo_flash_api" class="vjs-tech" width="100%" height="100%" name="tkavideo_flash_api" data="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param value="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf" name="movie">
<param value="readyFunction=_V_.flash.onReady&eventProxyFunction=_V_.flash.onEvent&errorEventProxyFunction=_V_.flash.onError&autoplay=false&preload=none&loop=false&muted=false&src=http%3A%2F%2Fready-for-review.com%2Ftkasite%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F11%2Foceans-clip.mp4&" name="flashvars">
<param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
<param value="all" name="allowNetworking">
<param value="opaque" name="wmode">
<param value="#000000" name="bgcolor">
</object>
```

And here is my function for pausing the html5 video:

```
$j("a.flex-next").click(function(){
    $j('video').each(function() {
        $j(this).get(0).pause();
     });
});
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the video.js API to pause instead of working directly on the video elements

```
$j("a.flex-next").click(function(){
  $j('.video-js').each(function() {
    _V_($j(this).attr("id")).pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. That did the trick. Please note that there is an extra quotation mark before $j('.video-js') in the above code that should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is possible not knowing any labels in the swf but it's been a while since I was in Flash. Normally, those controls would be within the swf...but, you can download trials of different apps that will crack a .swf file...make a copy of the swf file, open it up and see if you can find any labels or the name of a movie clip on stage housing the vid.